# ibatis to_char date format not working

Tags: sql, ibatis

Below SQL code brings all the data except `XC.XBRD_REG_DATE` which I am trying to format the data.

**SQL Code:**

```
SELECT XC.XBRD_SEQ, XC.XBRD_NOTE_SEQ, XC.XBRD_GNUM, XC.XBRD_GSTEP, XC.XBRD_DEPTH, XC.XBRD_TITLE, XC.XBRD_PASSWORD, XC.XBRD_WRITER_ID, XC.XBRD_WRITER_NAME, XC.XBRD_WRITER_IP, XC.XBRD_CONTENT_THUM, XC.XBRD_CONTENT, XC.XBRD_READ_NUM, XC.XBRD_FILE_DOWN, XC.XBRD_FILE_NUM,XC.XBRD_COMMENT_NUM, XC.XBRD_VIEW_FG, XC.XBRD_NOTICE_CK, XC.XBRD_ANON_CK, XC.XBRD_HIDDEN_CK, XC.XBRD_DELETE_CK
, TO_CHAR(XC.XBRD_REG_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
, XBRD_MODIFY_DATE, XC.XBRD_NOTICE_DATE, XC.XBRD_OPEN_CK, XC.XBRD_VOTE_NUM, XC.XBRD_COMMENT_FG, XC.XBRD_DISPLAY_FG, XC.XBRD_DISPLAY_END
FROM XBOARD_CONTENTS XC 
WHERE XC.XBRD_SEQ = #xbrd_seq#
ORDER BY XC.XBRD_NOTE_SEQ DESC
```

Any mistakes in my code?

Comment: What version of `sql` are you using? Are you able to fetch date value without formatting ? Eg: `XC.XBRD_REG_DATE`. What is the datatype of `XC.XBRD_REG_DATE` ?

Comment: Try this at to_char : `convert(varchar(10), XC.XBRD_REG_DATE, 111) ` if you are using [Transact-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Did you try anything ? Are you able to fix the problem from the above comments